# How should I implement asynchronous function in Javascript with node.js and Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

So far I have seen that there are `setTimeout()`,`process.nextTick(function)` for asynchronous function however I have no clue as to how to use it. I have tried on my code since I need a asynchronous function right now but it will have `Can't set headers after they are sent.`

This is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

var updateRecord = function(db, req, callback) {
db.collection('documents').updateMany({ 'Item Description': 
req.body.itemDescrip }, {
    $set: { 'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty }
}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    console.log('Done');
    console.log(results);
    var cursor = db.collection('documents').find({
        'Item Description': req.body.itemDescrip,
        'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty
    });
    var temp = [];
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else{
        console.log('Successfully queried');
        console.log(doc);
        temp.push(JSON.stringify(doc));
        }
    });
    callback(null, temp);
});
};

 module.exports = {
    postCollection: function(req, res) {
    var issueQty = req.body.issueQty;
    var itemDescrip = req.body.itemDescrip;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
          res.send(err);
          res.end();
          db.close();
          return;
        }
        updateRecord(db, req, function(err, doc) {
            if(err){
              res.send(err);
            }
            else{
              //setTimeout(function(){
                  res.send(doc);
            //},2000);
            }
            res.end();
            db.close();
        });

    });
 }
}
```

Basically I am trying to implement an asynchronous function such that it will execute the `updateRecord` first before sending a response down below as right now without the `setTimeout`, all I get it `[]` due to executing both simultaneously. This is for my web api which I am testing via postman. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Update:
Finally it worked! However my output has `\`included in it which is rather weird since I did not put `\`in the db. This is according to Roman Maksimov code below.

```
[
  "{\"_id\":\"18A\",\"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards\":\"\",\"Item Description\":\"Auresys EZL Prod\",\"Corrupted QTY\":\"\",\"Closing QTY\":\"100\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"Opening QTY\":\"1000\",\"Issued QTY\":\"100\"}",
  "{\"_id\":\"20\",\"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards\":\"\",\"Item Description\":\"Auresys EZL Prod\",\"Corrupted QTY\":\"\",\"Closing QTY\":\"100\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"Opening QTY\":\"1000\",\"Issued QTY\":\"100\"}",
  "null"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.each` is asynchronous, so, having the callback inside it may achieve unexpected results.

An easier way to achieve what you want is to remove the `each` function from the cursor and use the toArray method of mongodb. Add the final callback inside the toArray callback

```
var cursor = db.collection('documents').find({
  'Item Description': req.body.itemDescrip,
  'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty
}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  return callback(null, docs)
});
```

Comment: Great answer! From what you are saying, usually how do you decide which function to use for `cursor.each` or `toArray` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. But if you want the results in an Array manner, toArray seems applicable. I'm not sure of a use case for `each`, as I may as well just use JavaScript's array method to manipulate the results.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your are do it under the `Node.js` (Am I right?). From your desciription it's not clear what are you really want to reach. But, obviously, you can't send a body to a response since you have ended it (from this point the response is already sent to the client and, of course, it's not possible to write to it). Try this:

```js
updateRecord(db, req, function(err, doc) {
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
        res.end();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            res.send(doc);
            res.end();
        }, 2000);
    }
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help however I am not sure exactly what was it that went wrong in my code. Do you mean that the problem was with `db.close()`? And was hoping to clarify about `\ `in my output. Really appreciate your help allowing me to solve this problem.

Comment: No. I mean the problem was with `res.end()`. Since you have ended the response, you can't write to it.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the clarification. I understand what you mean.

Comment: About ```\```. This is the result of `temp.push(JSON.stringify(doc));` Your are converting your result to a JSON string. So, as a result, you get escapesed quotes. Try to add origin object, like this `temp.push(doc);`

Comment: Would that be due to the double quotes in the json code in mongodb?

Comment: No. This is how the `JSON.stringify()` method works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify